# Springboot build executable jar failed

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I've got an error message like this while building executable jar in IntelliJ, using Maven Projects -> Lifecycle -> package

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

but when i put my local postgres password in hibernate.cfg it works.

Why building jar must connect to database to work?

The problem is my local postgres and server postgres password are not the same, i can change my local postgres to have same password, but it will be a problem if i have multiple server with different password for different project.

Answer (score 1):

If you use application.properties you must set up the connection like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/yourdb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=sql
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using hibernate.cfg.xml, though i tried your method, and remove password and username in hibernate.cfg.xml, now it won't even run on local server with this error message org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided.